# Which coordinate system is used in "gstat" package in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, gstat

I am confused about which coordinate system is used in `gstat` package in R-language and also in `geoR` package in R-language.

Answer (score 0):

gstat and geoR are packages for geostatistical analysis. They will work with data that are in a geographical coordinate reference system. I think this chapter will help you to understand the concepts and it will illustrate the tools: https://bookdown.org/robinlovelace/geocompr/spatial-class.html#crs-intro